# Different customDepthMaterial for every material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a tree model, that consists from only one mesh and has two materials: bark and branch. I export this mesh from Blender to .json and than add it on the scene:

```
var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('models/branch1.png');
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("models/treeTest.json", function (geometry, materials) {
    materials.forEach(function (material) {
        material.alphaTest = 0.5;
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
    mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
        depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
        map: texture2,
        alphaTest: 0.5
    } );
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Result:

[image: threejs screenshot]

As you can see branches and bark use the same customDepthMaterial and because of that they have same shadows. I need to give customDepthMaterial only to branches, trunk must stay not transparent. I have tried to add customDepthMaterial on material with this:

```
materials.forEach(function (material) {
    material.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
        depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
        map: texture2,
        alphaTest: 0.5
    } );
});
```

but this code doesnt work (no errors in console, shadows just doesnt have transparency).

I know, that I can split my mesh into two parts (branches and trunk) and than use ObjectLoader, but I need the better solution.

Comment: Yes, this is an unfortunate limitation of the API. three.js r.88.

Comment: @WestLangley But this page says that Material can use CustomDepthMaterial. [link](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material)

Comment: Oh great. That documentation is misleading.